# Laravel/Angular: passing data within php page to angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4

I have the following laravel html/blade page and i want to pass in a **storeid** that then can get picked up via angular to then use to get and do some workings with.

Below is how i am accomplishing it NOW but is there a better way to produce the same?

**Blade Partial**

```
<div ng-controller="storeChartCtrl" data-storeid="{{ $store['id'] }}">
    <p>{{ $store['name'] }} Sales</p>
    ...
</div>
```

**Angular Ctrl**

```
.controller('storeChartCtrl', ['$scope', 'Store', function($scope, Store){
    //-- get the requested store sales
    var storeid = JQ('#storeChart').data('storeid');

    $log.info(storeid);
    ....
```

This currently works and i get my storeid value so i can then send to my factory to get the data.

Comment: This might help? https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: Ah the good old laracasts to js method, nice. Will consider but seems a little overkilll for that data (regret saying that as app gets bigger). Thanks will probably apply

Comment: @TheShiftExchange add this as an answer so i can mark it, worked, don't know why i did not think of this from the start :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Angular (or even just jQuery), I thank [@JeffreyWay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/890576/jeffreyway) for this package:

https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: I know this is old, but this doesn't seem to be working for me. The script is getting attached, and I can see all of the data, however, angular is saying that it's undefined.

Comment: Nevermind... my code goggles prevented me from seeing a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you are rendering an HTML page from the server with certain data embedded; you can either embed data inside your HTML, or you can "render" an object full of data in the page like so:

```
<?php
$value = "Hello";
$bob = "Bob";

// template code

<script type="text/javascript">
myData = {             // make it global for easy access
    blah: $value,
    alice: $bob
};
</script>
?>
```

and then in your Angular controller, you access that data in pure JS, without needing to juggle data attributes.

```
.controller('storeChartCtrl', ['$scope', 'Store', function($scope, Store){
    console.log(myData);
})]);
```

Comment: Thank for this it seems adding to the global scope etc like yours and the laracasts php vars to js is one way to go, especially when there is the requirement for more than more a few items to pass and the data attr is then not fesible, thasnk again

Comment: Thanks went with the laravel implementation method as suited best, but  in simply terms it does a similar thing. Thaksn for the reply though

Comment: This method is totaly ok.
I recommend namespacing your injected data to reduce overall global scope polution.