# angularjs ng-click or ng-init? php variables

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

I'm new in angularjs and after looking in every site and forum without answer, somebody can help me to selve this?

i have this html with php code, and i want to pass php var into angularjs event.

```
 <a ng-init="changeCat=<?php echo $id_cat, $category; ?>" id="cat_<?php echo $id_cat; ?>" class="cat-list" href="#"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: And, what does the resulting html look like after you php is executed? You're using php to write an angular template, so you should test that it writes the template correctly first, before trying to use the template.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a method `changeCat()` you can pass it php variables using something like `ng-init="changeCat(<?php echo $id_cat; ?>)"`.  I am assuming you want `ng-int` at this point but it should give you enough to get going with.

also try searching 'pass php to ng' or 'pass php variable to angular controller'... results should be similar.

**EDIT:**

As `@Kevin B` said you may want to change the way you are doing things but that said.

If you are to use more that one variabel then have a look at this:
[Laravel/Angular: passing data within php page to angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327547/laravel-angular-passing-data-within-php-page-to-angularjs)

Comment: tks!!! MrPickles for your help, is very hard to find documentation related with angularja and php, i'll try your solution and i'll comment!

Comment: @user3585926 that's because generally you don't use php to build angular templates, instead you build php webservices that return json to angular, then angular controllers/views/services take that data and build the page.

Comment: it works! but when i try to pass more than one var it shows me an error, this is the code with the second var, <?php echo $id_cat;.$category->name; ?>